# LINQ anonymous object is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.5, anonymous-types

I have LINQ logic that collects regex parsed data into a dynamically-created dictionary. The issue I am facing is accessing the data in the dictionary (`Info`).

```
Regex
    .Matches(text, pattern,
        RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture) 
    .OfType<Match>()    
    .Select(mt => new
    {
        Info = mt.Groups["ADKey"].Captures
            .OfType<Capture>()
            .Select(cp => cp.Value)
            .Zip(mt.Groups["ADValue"].Captures.OfType<Capture>().Select(cp => cp.Value),
                (k, v) => new { key = k, value = v })
            .ToDictionary(cp => cp.key, cp => cp.value),
        Nodes = mt.Groups["Key"].Captures
            .OfType<Capture>()
            .Select(cp => cp.Value)
            .Zip(mt.Groups["Value"].Captures.OfType<Capture>().Select(cp => cp.Value),
                (k, v) => new { key = k, value = v })
            .ToDictionary(cp => cp.key, cp => cp.value),
    });

List<string> myInfo = new List<string>();
myInfo = Info.Keys.ToList();
```

When I try to access the dictionary(info), while converting to list, I get the error that "Info" is inaccessible due to its protection level. How do I fix that?

Comment: Do you understand the compiler error?

Comment: no, I do not. should have mentioned that Ive been a "developer" for about 2 weeks. I'm a DBA by trade.

Comment: `Info` is not a variable. You forgot to assign `Regex...` to variable.

Comment: if you do Info = Regex. etc you will get an IEnumerable<Info> where Info is an anonymous data type. Select( t => new { }) creates anonymous types

Comment: @user2219930 - You say you need to access "**the** dictionary", but you're creating a sequence of dictionaries. What are you hoping to do with a sequence of `Info` dictionaries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently creating a list of anonymous types which have a single property, `Info`, that is a `Dictionary<string, string>`. You don't appear to be capturing the result in a variable. Then you try to access `Info` as if it were a single object outside of the `RegEx` query. Those two `Info` reference different things.

The first suggestion I have for you is to change your code like this:

```
IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, string>> query =
    Regex
        .Matches(
            text,
            pattern,
            RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
                | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture) 
        .OfType<Match>()
        .Select(mt => mt.Groups["Key"].Captures
                .OfType<Capture>()
                .Select(cp => cp.Value)
                .Zip(
                    mt.Groups["Value"].Captures
                        .OfType<Capture>()
                        .Select(cp => cp.Value),
                    (k, v) => new
                    {
                        key = k,
                        value = v
                    })
                .ToDictionary(cp => cp.key, cp => cp.value));
```

Now, I don't believe you want a `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, string>>`, because on your next two lines you seem to want the to pull the keys straight out of the results.

It appears that you might want this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> query =
    Regex
        .Matches(text, pattern,
            RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
                | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture) 
        .OfType<Match>()
        .SelectMany(mt => mt.Groups["Key"].Captures
            .OfType<Capture>()
            .Select(cp => cp.Value)
            .Zip(
                mt.Groups["Value"].Captures
                    .OfType<Capture>()
                    .Select(cp => cp.Value),
                (k, v) => new
                {
                    key = k,
                    value = v
                }))
        .ToDictionary(cp => cp.key, cp => cp.value);
```

But I suspect this will have key collisions.

I think you probably want something like this:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(text, pattern,
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
        | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);

Dictionary<string, string> result =
    match
        .Groups["Key"]
        .Captures
        .OfType<Capture>()
        .Select(cp => cp.Value)
        .Zip(
            match.Groups["Value"].Captures
                .OfType<Capture>()
                .Select(cp => cp.Value),
            (k, v) => new
            {
                key = k,
                value = v
            })
        .ToDictionary(cp => cp.key, cp => cp.value);
```

Then you can do this:

```
    List<string> myInfo = result.Keys.ToList();
```

---

Given your updated question it seems to me you might want this:

```
Match match =
    Regex.Match(text, pattern,
        RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
            | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);

var result = new
{
    Info = match.Groups["ADKey"].Captures
        .OfType<Capture>()
        .Select(cp => cp.Value)
        .Zip(match.Groups["ADValue"].Captures.OfType<Capture>().Select(cp => cp.Value),
            (k, v) => new { key = k, value = v })
        .ToDictionary(cp => cp.key, cp => cp.value),
    Nodes = match.Groups["Key"].Captures
        .OfType<Capture>()
        .Select(cp => cp.Value)
        .Zip(match.Groups["Value"].Captures.OfType<Capture>().Select(cp => cp.Value),
            (k, v) => new { key = k, value = v })
        .ToDictionary(cp => cp.key, cp => cp.value),
};

List<string> myInfo = result.Info.Keys.ToList();
```

Comment: the reason i did it that way is because i have multiple anonymous objects in the query. I originally shortened it for readability, but i see now that was a mistake. I have updated the question with the full linq query. I need to be able to access both dictionaries inside.

Comment: You have one anonymous type with two properties, each of which is a dictionary - the main point still stands, you aren't actually storing the result of your query in a variable. Whatever `Info` is in the line `myInfo = Info.Keys.ToList();` it's *not* the result of your query.

Comment: thanks very much. this has gotten me through my issues. as a matter of fact, just know what to google (anonymous object) was a big help. i apologize for the lack of clarity, but I'm new at this.

thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

I got a similar error:

> EnumerableExtensions.Join(IEnumerable, string)' is
> inaccessible due to its protection level

Then realized that I forgot to include using `System.Linq;` in the code.